# Combobox in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, combobox, sencha-touch

How we can realize a Combobox with sencha touch??

I tried with `selectfield` but when I install my app on an Android Phone, the select field doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 xtype: 'selectfield',
 label: 'Choose one',
 options: [
            {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
            {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
            {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
          ]
```

This is code straight from the sencha site. Select field works on Android. There must be something else wrong in your code.

Comment: SALAM. thank you for your response. i tried this same code but it doesnt work. I installed my app on the Galaxy S Ft-I9000 version android 2.3.2 and the selectfield doesn't appear.